# Jenkins Declarative sequential pipelines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sequential, declarative

Why does this not work? (https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#sequential-stages)
I created a pipeline with the following...

```
pipeline {
agent none
stages {
    stage('Non-Sequential Stage') {
        agent {
            label 'for-non-sequential'
        }
        steps {
            echo "On Non-Sequential Stage"
        }
    }
    stage('Sequential') {
        agent {
            label 'for-sequential'
        }
        environment {
            FOR_SEQUENTIAL = "some-value"
        }
        stages {
           stage('In Sequential 1') {
               steps {
                   echo "In Sequential 1"
               }
           }
           stage('In Sequential 2') {
               steps {
                   echo "In Sequential 2"
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I am getting the following

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed: WorkflowScript: 12: Unknown stage section "stages".
>   Starting with version 0.5, steps in a stage must be in a steps block.
>   @ line 12, column 9.
>              stage('Sequential') {
>              ^
>
> WorkflowScript: 12: No "steps" or "parallel" to execute within stage
>   "Sequential" @ line 12, column 9.
>              stage('Sequential') {
>              ^
>
> 2 errors
>
> at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
>     at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
>     at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
>     at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)     at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)   at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:131)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:125)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:560)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:521)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:325)
>     at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
>     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429) Finished: FAILURE

Comment: You cannot do nested stages (unless you consider parallel stages to be nested) and, last I saw, Cloudbees explicitly stated they have no plans to develop that functionality. That documentation is alarmingly inaccurate. I think the impetus behind this is that it would mess up the BlueOcean viewer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Matt. I guessed as much but was curious because of the documentation.

Comment: So this is actually about to be implemented: https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/07/02/whats-new-declarative-piepline-13x-sequential-stages/